# Counting degree-consistent total orders of the vertices a certain type of rooted tree

Tags: combinatorics

So that's an ugly title, and there's several possible ways to state this problem, and I'm not certain that the tree version is the clearest, but here goes:
If a tree has two adjacent vertices of degree $n$, one of which is designated as the root, no vertices of degree greater than $n$, and every vertex of degree $m$ is adjacent to exactly one vertex of degree $k$ for every $k\lt m$, how many ways are there to order the vertices such that for two adjacent vertices $a$ and $b$, $a<b$ implies $degree(a)<degree(b)$ or $degree(a)=degree(b)$ and $b$ is the root? I'm not quite sure how to approach this one. I'd be equally interested in an explicit formula or a recurrence relation, or just suggestions on a plan of attack to count this.

Comment: another way to describe what I'm trying to count is the number of ways to build such a tree by tacking on one vertex at a time, starting with the degree $n$ vertex, and keeping the tree connected at each step, or by reversing the order, to remove the vertices one-at-a-time, only removing vertices of rank 1.

Comment: just realized this makes no sense as stated.  I'm rewriting.  The description in the above comment might make clear what I'm looking for, but obviously the property I stated is impossible.  It's the product of trying to frame in terms of degree what makes more sense with a rooted tree.

Comment: there, I think I've got it properly stated now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So obviously I was really tired yesterday, because when I looked at this problem for a couple of minutes this morning, the recurrence was obvious:$$a_0=1$$ $$a_{n+1}={a_n^2\over2}{2^{n+1} \choose 2^n}$$
There might be a way to simplify this further, but this is good enough for my purposes.

Edit:
A generalization of the above recurrence which I found even more useful was $$a_n=2^n!{a_{n-k}\over 2^{n-k}!}\left({a_k\over 2^k!}\right)^{2^{n-k}}$$ for any $k<n$. If we let $k=n-1$, we get the original recurrence.